# Reading shared variables from LabView in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, variables, shared, labview

I have a shared variable in LabView and I want to read it on my Android application written in Java. Does anybody know how could I do it?

Comment: Please clarify your problem? Add more content or code.

Comment: According to this [NI page](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/lvconcepts/ni_psp/) the shared variable protocol is proprietary. That doesn't mean you can't read it, but I don't think it's documented by NI. You could try this question on the NI forums, or if you can change the LabVIEW code you could add something to publish the data using something like UDP.

Comment: Maybe try wireshark and see what it shows... hmmm.. an interesting project idea?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by some other users, NI's Shared Variable interface is proprietary, and is only supported through using their products.  However, there are a few workarounds I can think of:

1. If there is a LabVIEW or TestStand instance generating the values for the shared variables, you could send the data via UDP or TCP directly to the java application, instead of, or in addition to, writing to the variables.
2. You are able to tie Shared Variables to OPC variables within the NI software.  This requires having an OPC server to write these values to (Which NI also has-it's a re-skin of Kepware), but there are many options for reading OPC variables using Java.
3. Basic file I/O, as also previously mentioned, could be possible depending on the system layout.
4. With LabVIEW you can deploy RESTful web services which will execute specific VI's upon receiving requests.  You may be able to leverage these to retrieve the values of the shared variables you are targeting.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest your best bet is to write the value out to a file using LabVIEW and read it in JAVA or open an network connection/RabbitMQ pipe between the two applications.